# Magento set content in action

Tags: magento, controller, set

I'm quite new to Magento

And I'm creating the payment module which redirects to PaymentController

I have redirectAction

And I need to solve a simple task:

I need to show the content from a .phtml file in

```
$this->loadLayout();
    $cmsBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_block_fail');

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($cmsBlock);

    $this->renderLayout();
    return $this;
```

And nothing is showing up

All I need is just to show some html in the main site layout

Comment: Perform a sanity check. Use die() or a direct echo to make sure you are reaching this bit of code. After that, Check the Layout.

Comment: I want to make a better question: I get an action and I want to show my "response.html" inside the main "content".  I.e. if I had <body> {$content}</body variable in the template - I want to replace it with my own from HTML template with all header and footer which goes with the main template. Just set my own content on the page. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> Use registry to pass data to template.

Create registry on controller and and display into phtml file.

check below link how to create registry:-
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-set-and-get-registry/